# Is it possible to add table cells dynamically and give them a different id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpKMQ/) you see a table with a select-field where you should select a name.
Below there are 5 input-fields where one could type in some text and 3 input-fields which are set to readonly.

I wanted to ask whether there is a way to add table cells dynamically when clicking on the button. The result should like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qE79W/). The id should be incremented by i+.
I tried cloning the code, but could't figure out how to do increment the id of the cloned input-field. The only input-fields I do not want to clone are the readonly input-fields.

Do you have an example code or a link you would recommend? A hint to start would be helpful as well.

I've been searching the net already, but wasn't able to find something.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're [using tables](http://www.shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/) for this? Tables are more awkward to manipulate DOM-wise, if you can get away with not using them, I would.

Comment: The input-fields will be filled with numbers. There will be a tabulation. I do calculate with those numbers later on. Those will appear in the readonly input-fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you ask (*i added an `id` to the button to target it easy*)

```
  $('#add').click(function(){

    $(this)
        .closest('table')
        .find('tr td:first-child:not(:has([readonly]))')
        .each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this
                .clone()
                .each(function(){
                    var $inp = $(':input',this);
                    var id = $inp.attr('id');
                    var idwithoutnum = id.replace(/([0-9]+)$/,'');
                    var maxId = $(':input[id^='+idwithoutnum+']:last').attr('id');
                    var idnum = parseInt(/([0-9]+)$/.exec(maxId)) + 1;
                    var newid = id.replace(/([0-9]+)$/,idnum);
                    $inp.attr('id', newid);
                    alert(newid); // remove this line
                })
                .insertAfter($this
                             .closest('tr')
                             .find('td:last')
                            );
    });
});
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/fMZDd/7/

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out. Have you got an idea how I do increment the id of the input-fields. +1

Comment: Hi, again. Just wanted to let you know that the input-field ids are not incrementing correctly. After incrementing them a third time the number addition to the id will be always 2. I'm on it, but got my issues.

Comment: @Faili, you are right.. updated code (*minor*) and example. **Note** : i have removed the button from the inner table and placed it on the outer, so i can target the last column without it getting in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose not to use tables for dom manipulation. Either way, here is how you could do it.

to add a table cell

```
var td = document.createElement("td")
var idVals = prevId.match(/^([a-z_]*)([0-9]+)$/)
td.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='"+ idVals[1] + (parseInt(idVals[2]) + 1) +">";
tr.appendChild(td)
```

Hope this helps.